# Usage of word polished in different contexts

Tags: word-usage, word-meaning

One of the meanings of the word polished is `accomplished and skilful` or `refined, sophisticated, or elegant`.

How did this kind of word `polish` which probably literally means `shiny` but is being used in multiple ways and in the above-mentioned ways like `elegant` or `sophisticated` which could be guessed because polished -> shiny -> could mean shine in personality...

What is this called in English? Many such words having a different meanings are being used in a different way, kind of like applying to a different thing. like one could polish a wall or diamond. Probably thats what it meant earlier but then it got more meanings like polishing personality..

Does this type of applying the word in a different scenario which alters the meaning have a certain `name` or definition or some rules. By rule I mean which words could be used in such a way?

Answer (score 2):

Polishing is the final stage in preparing high quality metal or leather objects. So saying something is polished means that it is finished to a high quality - this transfers *figuratively* to saying that a person has finished their social education and so are socially elegant and high quality.

This is called **figurative** language, and is common in all natural languages including English and your native language.

There are many types of figurative language: metaphor, synecdoche, hyperbole,  and personification.

This is an example of metaphor.

There is no grammatical limit on what words can be used metaphorically. But idiomatically, some metaphors are more common, and sometimes the metaphorical meaning becomes the main meaning. But poets are constantly making new metaphors and using other forms of figurative speech.

Comment: Wow that was interesting. Could you suggest some books to go deeper into this aspect of the language? I am very interested in deepening my knowledge of English. Could you recommend reading some poetry books/English language books/Websites/Authors that one could follow?

Comment: You should probably start by understanding this in your native language. What metaphors are used?  What types of figurative language?  There are lots of poets, too many to recommend,  pick any one you like.